# TabbedView similar to Spotify

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I'm making research for UI to my new app, main purpose is displaying products on something like horizontal imageList/tabbedView looking like spotify app. My main problem is how to get displaying "previews" of next and previous product on left and right side of screen. Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a `Carousel`. There are some libraries that can help you do that. Have a look at these :

- [Carousel layout android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/carousel-layout-android/)
- [Android 3d carousel view](https://github.com/radhoo/android-3d-carousel-view)
- [Android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/154)
- [here](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/making-carousel-layout-in-android.html)'s a tutorial

and of course the most helpful :

- [Carousel android](https://www.google.co.in/#q=carousel+android)

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for!