# How to resize an image when it's scrolled over in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently I'm using `RecyclerView` to display 3 images horizontally.

I would like the view to look like so:

[image: Scrollable layout]

So that when I scroll to the left/right the images resize depending on their position in the row (center image being the largest).

Is there a way to do this in android, using `RecyclerView` or something else?

Thank you for any help

Comment: With RecyclerView you need to check center position image.. So my suggestion is to use Gallery View or Cover Flow..

For CoverFlow :

https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

For Gallery View :

http://www.androidinterview.com/android-gallery-view-example-displaying-a-list-of-images/

Comment: @ChiragArora Thank you so much, I like the look of CoverFlow, I will try that out.

Comment: Yes coverflow is good .. :)

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117357/tabbedview-similiar-to-spotify/

Answer (score 1):

Use horizontal `RecyclerView`,Like

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

In Adapter onBindview,
by getting the item position try to change the image size.

Link : http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/11/gallery-like-recyclerview-cardview.html